# java expand mathematical equations

Tags: java, math

Is there a java library that expand mathematical equations?

for example

(x – 4)^2 + (y + 1)^2 = 9

i would like to output the developed form

x^2 + y^2 – 8x + 2y + 8 = 0

Comment: Probably. But wouldn't it be more fun & educational to write one yourself?

Comment: Also, this is not a linear equation.

Comment: I checked around and found nothing noteworthy. What you could do is simply read it in as a string and do some regex magic and looping.

Comment: yeah i edited it to remove the term linear :P, and thank you for your answers, i will try to write it myself.

Comment: @JohnMikaelGundersen: [xkcd.com/1171/](http://xkcd.com/1171/)

Comment: @jlordo Ah, true, but working with strings this way it _COULD_ be a solution.

Comment: Take a look at [Is there something like Sympy for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574949/is-there-something-like-sympy-for-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is tool for performing "Symbolic Math".

A quick search revealed a couple of options:

- http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas
- http://code.google.com/p/symja
- http://meditorworld.appspot.com/meditor.txt.

Hope that helps.

Edit: This question was closed so I originally posted this as a comment.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/symja (polynomial expand) is what i am looking for, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called [**Computer Algebra System**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system).

I just googled "Java Computer Algebra System" and the first hit was [symja](http://code.google.com/p/symja/). I haven't tried it.

If this library is not appropriate for you then you find a [list of CAS software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_algebra_systems) on Wikipedia.

As [@Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113141/justin) points out, a related question is: [Is there something like Sympy for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2574949/341970)

Answer (score -1):

This is string manipulation, not mathematical term manipulation.  You will likely have to write one yourself.  There are several ways of doing this, with varying degrees of interesting-ness

Comment: How is this not mathematical term manipulation? Symbolic math is a common problem with a variety of available libraries, no need to write something from scratch.